# "no such file or directory" when importing daloradius schema

Tags: command-line, apt, mysql

I have already installed daloradius using the commands :

```
cd ~
wget https://github.com/lirantal/daloradius/archive/master.zip
sudo apt-get install unzip
unzip master.zip
```

but when I import the daloradius schema to our radius database  using the command:

```
mysql -u freeradius -p radius < daloradius-0.9-9/contrib/db/fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql
```

an error showed: `no such file or directory`

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `daloradius-0.9-9/contrib/db/fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql` doesn't actually exist because the file was extracted elsewhere.

However, you don't need to download the entire repository tree if you just need that one file. This should be enough:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lirantal/daloradius/master/contrib/db/fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql
mysql -u freeradius -p radius < fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
unzip -l master.zip |grep fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql
unzip -x master.zip daloradius-master/contrib/db/fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql
cat daloradius-master/contrib/db/fr2-mysql-daloradius-and-freeradius.sql|mysql -u freeradius -p radius
```

Comment: Cause of the data inside "billing_history" 
  `creditcardname` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `creditcardnumber` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `creditcardverification` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `creditcardtype` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `creditcardexp` varchar(200) default NULL,

please protect this mysql database ! (use da crypted file system for the database files and protect access to this data)

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat)